# "My X is to be Y-ing Z" Is this gramatically correct?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, grammaticality, present-participles

For example:
"My goal is to be leading a team of people that are skilled in construction."
Is this gramatically correct or not?

edit: I know "My goal is to lead a team" is better, but is the above sentence still correct or not?

Comment: People are not things, **people that are** should be **people who are**. Otherwise "My goal is to be leading ..." is as good as "My goal is to lead ..."

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, it's as good as "My goal is to lead", but is "My goal is to be leading" still correct or not?

Comment: Didn't I say "as good as"?

Comment: @WeatherVane Okay then sorry miss I was just trying to clarify.

Comment: I pointed out the fault: **that** ==> **who**.

Comment: Oh okay. My concern is more about the "is to be leading x" part, didn't really care about the words after "that". Thanks!

Comment: You might get more feedback than you expected. You asked "Is this gramatically correct or not?"

Comment: Okay sorry. I won't do it again.

Comment: Please ask again, but read the comments.

Comment: However, "as good as" does not mean interchangeable.  There are shades of meaning in your examples without enough context to distinguish between scenarios.

Comment: @Gossar what does it mean then?

Comment: As an extreme example, "This pen is red" and "This pen is not red" are both grammatical but only one will be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes it is correct.**

It does sound a bit awkward to me, a native English speaker, but it is correct. Most people would use the simplified sentence you provided, but some do use "be" with an "ing"  verb in that context.